# Passing an inline function expression as argument to a regular function

Tags: javascript, function

I wanted to pass my inline function expression as a argument to a regular function declaration.

Here is the code.

```
    function emotions(myString, myFunc) {
    console.log("I am " + myString + ", " + myFunc(2));
}

var laugh = function func(num){
    var l = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
        l += "ha";
    }
    return l + '!';
};

  emotions("happy", function func(num));
```

The Output should be "I am happy, haha!"

But I am getting a syntax error in JS console: "Unexpected token".
I am really unable to figure what's wrong with my program. So, somebody please figure out what i am doing wrong?

Comment: `function emotions("happy", function func(num));` is a declaration, not a function call. The parameters are invalid literals

Comment: @Mvarta actually I wanted to write emotions("happy", function func(num)); it was a typo . So I am editing my question.

Comment: I understand just passing "laugh" will yield correct output. But the programming question I was trying to solve was directed to pass inline function expression instead of "laugh". When I did this I ended up with that error I cited in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong is you have two syntax errors:

```
function emotions("happy", function func(num));
// ------------------------------------------^^
```

...because you have an incomplete function declaration and an incomplete function expression there.

If you want to call `emotions` and pass in `laugh`, just refer to it:

```
emotions("happy", laugh);
```

You've assigned your "ha ha" function to `laugh` earlier, so you can just use it there. Functions are first-class values in JavaScript, not a separate thing like some other languages.

Notice there's no `function` keyword in front of `emotions`. You only use the `function` keyword when *creating* functions, not when calling them.

Live Example:

```js
function emotions(myString, myFunc) {
    console.log("I am " + myString + ", " + myFunc(2));
}

var laugh = function func(num){
    var l = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
        l += "ha";
    }
    return l + '!';
};

emotions("happy", laugh);
```

Answer (score 0):

`function func(num)` is kind of a function declaration, amd it is missing the body. To just pass the function, just take `func`, but in this case your functions name is actually `laugh`.

```
const emotion(state, laugh) => `I am ${state}, ${laugh(2)}!`;

const ha = n => "ha".repeat(n);

console.log(emotion("happy", ha));
```